# Background of fixed position div extends beyond edge of pop-up

Tags: css

I've created a scrollable pop-up that uses a jQuery plugin to hold the buttons in place at the top of the window as a user scrolls. This works except for one small problem...the white background that I have placed on the `div` containing the buttons (in order to prevent seeing the content scrolling beneath the buttons) is extending beyond the right edge of the pop-up. I've tried this in both Chrome and Firefox and they both do the same thing. Is there a CSS solution to this problem?

Here's my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/donnapep/NhmvH/2/

HTML

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="wrapper container modal-content">
    <div>
        <h1>Weather Settings</h1>
        <div class="sticky-wrapper">
            <div class="btn-toolbar sticky-buttons">
                <button id="save" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Save</button>
                <button id="cancel" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Cancel</button>
                <button id="help" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Help</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<form role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="layout">Layout</label>
                <div class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="layout" value="current" data-url="http://s3.amazonaws.com/Widget-Weather-Test/current.html" checked="checked">
                    <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/Widget-Weather-Test/images/thumbs/current-vertical.png" class="img-thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/Widget-Weather-Test/images/thumbs/current-horizontal.png" class="img-thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="layout" value="three-day" data-url="http://s3.amazonaws.com/Widget-Weather-Test/three-day.html">
                    <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/Widget-Weather-Test/images/thumbs/three-day-vertical.png" class="img-thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/Widget-Weather-Test/images/thumbs/three-day-horizontal.png" class="img-thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="layout" value="current-and-three-day" data-url="http://s3.amazonaws.com/Widget-Weather-Test/current-and-three-day.html" checked="checked">
                    <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/Widget-Weather-Test/images/thumbs/current-and-three-day-vertical.png" class="img-thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/Widget-Weather-Test/images/thumbs/current-and-three-day-horizontal.png" class="img-thumbnail">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.wrapper {
    z-index: 2;
    width: 90%;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
.sticky-buttons {
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sticky-buttons").sticky({
        container: $(".wrapper"),
        topSpacing: 21
    });
});
```

Thx.

Comment: It's not happening for me on Chrome nor Firefox on my Mac. You can always use the `calc()` for width. (e.g. `width: calc(100% - 20px)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**http://jsfiddle.net/4eAeA/**

Looking at the **[docs](https://github.com/garand/sticky)** for that plugin you can use  `getWidthFrom` as an option argument.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sticky-buttons").sticky({
        container: $(".wrapper"),
        topSpacing: 21,
        getWidthFrom : $(".wrapper")
    });
});
```

@donnapep, a downside I saw from that plugin is that it does not keep the width in check on resize.

You will also need something like this :

```
var _stickybuttons = $(".sticky-buttons");
$(window).resize(function () {
   _stickybuttons.sticky('update');
});
```

Comment: Bah, I should have saw that. Thank you!

Comment: @donnapep, great stuff. I have just added a useful update as a the plugin does not look to have a feature of keeping width in check if the window is resized.

Comment: Good point. I'll see about reporting this to the plugin's creator. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your jquery to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sticky-wrapper").sticky({
        container: $(".wrapper"),
        topSpacing: 21
    });
});
```

Some `position:absolute;` to

```
.wrapper.container.modal-content
```

so that it does not extend to the right
and

```
width:100%;
z-index:20;
```

in `.sticky-wrapper`

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/NhmvH/9/

It moves to left now but you get the idea.

Dont know if by changing your plugin its easier but anyway I hope it helps a bit.